# Get all features in decision path to leaf node (Random Forest)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I have the following example code for a simple random forest classifier on the iris dataset using just 2 decision trees. This code is best run inside a jupyter notebook.

```
# Setup
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
# Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1015)

# Load the iris data
iris = load_iris()

# Create the train-test datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target)

np.random.seed(1039)

# Just fit a simple random forest classifier with 2 decision trees
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 2)
rf.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train)

# Define a function to draw the decision trees in IPython
# Adapted from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html
from IPython.display import display, Image
import pydotplus

# Now plot the trees individually
for dtree in rf.estimators_:
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree
                                    , out_file = None
                                    , filled   = True
                                    , rounded  = True
                                    , special_characters = True)  
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
    img = Image(graph.create_png())
    display(img)
    draw_tree(inp_tree = dtree)
    #print(dtree.tree_.feature)
```

The output for the first tree is:

[image]

As can be observed the first decision has **8 leaf nodes** and the second decision tree (not shown) has **6 leaf nodes**

How do I extract a simple numpy array which contains information for  each decision tree, and each leaf node in the tree:

- the classification outcome for that leaf node (e.g. **most frequent** class it predicted)
- all the features (boolean) used in the decision path to that same leaf node?

In the above example we would have:

- 2 trees - `{0, 1}`
- for tree `{0}` we have 8 leaf nodes indexed `{0, 1, ..., 7}`
- for tree `{1}` we have 6 leaf nodes indexed `{0, 1, ..., 5}`
- for each leaf node in each tree we have a **single most frequent predicted class** i.e. `{0, 1, 2}` for the *iris* dataset
- for each leaf node we have a set of boolean values for the 4 features that were used to make that tree. Here if one of the 4 features is used *one or more times* in the decision path to a leaf node we count it as a `True` otherwise `False` if it is never used in the decision path to the leaf node.

Any help adapting this `numpy` array into the above code (loop) is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the code in the `tree` class, in particular I think the code from the `export_graphiz` function is a good place to start https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/tree/export.py#L70

Comment: when I try to run your code I get __name 'draw_tree' is not defined__ any ideas why ?

Comment: @user4687531 when I try to run your code I get name 'draw_tree' is not defined any ideas why ?

Comment: The decision nodes are accessible in Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600290/how-extraction-decision-rules-of-random-forest-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the the questions here: [how extraction decision rules of random forest in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600290/how-extraction-decision-rules-of-random-forest-in-python)

You can use the snippet [@jonnor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967571/jonnor) provided (I used it modified as well):

```py
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics, datasets, ensemble

def print_decision_rules(rf):

    for tree_idx, est in enumerate(rf.estimators_):
        tree = est.tree_
        assert tree.value.shape[1] == 1 # no support for multi-output

        print('TREE: {}'.format(tree_idx))

        iterator = enumerate(zip(tree.children_left, tree.children_right, tree.feature, tree.threshold, tree.value))
        for node_idx, data in iterator:
            left, right, feature, th, value = data

            # left: index of left child (if any)
            # right: index of right child (if any)
            # feature: index of the feature to check
            # th: the threshold to compare against
            # value: values associated with classes            

            # for classifier, value is 0 except the index of the class to return
            class_idx = numpy.argmax(value[0])

            if left == -1 and right == -1:
                print('{} LEAF: return class={}'.format(node_idx, class_idx))
            else:
                print('{} NODE: if feature[{}] < {} then next={} else next={}'.format(node_idx, feature, th, left, right))    


digits = datasets.load_digits()
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target)
estimator = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3, max_depth=2)
estimator.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

---

Another approach and for visualization:

For visualizing the decision path you can use the library [dtreeviz](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) from https://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/index.html

They have fantastic visualizations like:
[image]

*Source https://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/images/samples/sweets-TD-3-X.svg*

Look at their [shadowDecisionTree](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/dtreeviz/models/shadow_decision_tree.py) implementation for getting more information on  the decision path. In https://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/index.html they also provide an example with

```py
shadow_tree = ShadowDecTree(tree_model, X_train, y_train, feature_names, class_names)
```

Then you could use something like the `get_leaf_sample_counts`method.